# PhantomJS Showing exit code 0 even after network error

Tags: phantomjs, exit-code

I am using PhantomJS for printing pdf from my web page and then storing the resultant pdf to S3 if the pdf is generated successfully.

My problem is PhantomJS is returning exit code 0 i.e. success even after a network error occur and the resultant pdf is not which I want.

So I want to know is there any way to abort PhantomJS when error occur with an exit code .

Currently the error in which this happening is NETWORK Error : 101
But even though PhantomJS do not abort and return with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

The only time that PhantomJS exits on its own is when it encounters a Syntax Error of your script (PhantomJS 2.0.0 has a bug and simply freezes and doesn't print anything at this point).

For everything else you need to call [`phantom.exit()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/method/exit.html) to exit. `phantom.exit()` takes an optional argument which is the exit code. So when you encounter an error for example by checking the `success` argument of the [`page.open()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) callback or when [`onResourceError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-error.html) or [`onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events are triggered, you can exit PhantomJS with your own intended exit code such as

```
phantom.exit(1);
```